# What is enough to store dates/times in the DB from multiple time zones for accurate calculations?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, timezone

This is a **HARD** question. In fact it is so hard it seems the SQL standard and most of the major databases out there don't have a clue in their implementation.

Converting all datetimes to UTC allows for easy comparison between records but throws away the timezone information, which means you can't do calculations with them (e.g. add 8 months to a stored datetime) nor retrieve them in the time zone they were stored in. So the naive approach is out.

Storing the timezone offset from UTC in addition to the timestamp (e.g. timestamp with time zone in postgres) would seem to be enough, but different timezones can have the same offset at one point in the year and a different one 6 months later due to DST. For example you could have New York and Chile both at UTC-4 now (August) but after the 4th of November New York will be UTC-5 and Chile (after the 2nd of September) will be UTC-3. So storing just the offset will not allow you to do accurate calculations either. Like the above naive approach it also discards information.

What if you store the timezone identifier (e.g. America/Santiago) with the timestamp instead? This would allow you to distinguish between a Chilean datetime and a New York datetime. But this still isn't enough. If you are storing an expiration date, say midnight 6 months into the future, and the DST rules change (as unfortunately politicians like to do) then your timestamp will be wrong and expiration could happen at 11 pm or 1 am instead. Which might or might not be a big deal to your application. So using a timestamp also discards information.

It seems that to truly be accurate you need to store the local datetime (e.g. using a non timezone aware timestamp type) with the timezone identifier. To support faster comparisons you could cache the utc version of it until the timezone db you use is updated, and then update the cached value if it has changed. So that would be 2 naive timestamp types plus a timezone identifier and some kind of external cron job that checks if the timezone db has changed and runs the appropriate update queries for the cached timestamp.

Is that an accurate solution? Or am I still missing something? Could it be done better?

I'm interested in solutions for MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL and other DBMS that handle TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Comment: Since you mention SQL Server, I'll point out the new (sort of new, 2008) DateTimeOffset datatype... *might* make this a little easier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289(v=sql.105).aspx In general, I think your approach is correct. Store all the info you need to make an accurate determination...this usually means at minimum UTC and TZ info.

Comment: @Tim A UTC timestamp is not enough, you also need the local datetime. From Dan's comment "September 1st, 1PM America/New_York" will always be 1 PM. But if it was converted to UTC, and the daylight time savings rules change you've lost the information that you meant it to be 1 pm in New York (reread my last paragraph)

Comment: @DanGrossman *"September 1st, 1PM America/New_York" will never become 12PM or 2PM no matter what DST does".*  If you store them as GMT/UTC with a separate named time zone then this isn't true.  DST for NY is the difference between being UTC-4 and UTC-5. So 12PM (UTC-4) is stored as 4PM UTC.  But if 01-Sep gets changed out of DST (for political reasons) then your stored 4PM UTC will be read as 11AM (UCT-5).  This was the point of his question.

Comment: @eloff - that's why I said "at minimum"...you might need to store more, and I think your approach is comprehensive. However (speaking from a Windows/.Net perspective) if you store the TZ and UTC, you can calculate what the local time would have been at time of storage, even if the rules have changed in the interim. The timezone info classes (again, speaking Windows/.Net) are smart enough to know when the rules went into effect. Other platforms should have similar libraries/logic, though there very well might be exceptional cases (e.g., Windows XP has a problem with dates prior to 2007).

Comment: @Tim I think you've answered my question in a comment. Looking deeper at the IANA timezone database I can see that it does infact contain the information needed to reconstruct past times. So you're right a UTC timestamp and timezone are enough to reconstruct them in the correct local time. Future dates need the local time and timezone (and possibly may need a cached utc timestamp for performance reasons.)

Comment: I'm wrong. Past times can change. A couple times a year the ZIC database gets historical corrections (e.g. retroactive changes to past timezones.) In this case the UTC timezone that would have been stored was actually stored wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've summarized the problem well.  Sadly the answer is to do what you've described.

The correct format to use does depend the pragmatics of what the timestamp is supposed to represent.  It can in general be divided between past and future events (though there are exceptions):

- Past events can and usually should be stored as something which can never be reinterpreted differently. (eg: a UTC time stamp with a numeric time zone).  If the named time zone should be kept (to be informative to the user) then this should be separate.
- Future events need the solution you've described. Local timestamp and named time zone.  This is because you want to change the "actual" (UTC) time of that event when the time zone rules change.

I would question if time zone conversion is such an overhead? It's usually pretty quick. I'd only go through the pain of caching if you are seeing a really significant performance hit.  There are (as you pointed out) some big operations which will require caching (such as sorting billions of rows based on the actual (UTC) time.

If you require future events to be cached in UTC for performance reasons then yes, you need to put a process in place to update the cached values.  Depending of the type of DB it is possible that this could be done by the sysadmins as TZ rules change rarely.

Comment: Well I'm thinking about common uses like SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY created_time. You can't do that efficiently if you have to perform some ad hoc conversion based on the time zone identifier and the local timestamp for every record in a table with billions of records. So the cached UTC value is necessary to do comparisons efficiently at the DB side.

Comment: Aggreed. As with all databases you need a feel for volume and the types of queries used before you can performance tune.  My gut feeling is that simply sorting a billion rows would be a much bigger overhead than the addition of translating the TZ.  But you and the OP are right; caching may be necessary.

Comment: Yep my gut feeling says your gut feeling is correct, but if you have an index on the cached utc value, then the database may be able to return the rows in sorted order using the index (depending if the optimizer's gut feeling thinks that's faster than sorting.)

Comment: @couling You are wrong. Timezone rules don't change for past time. If you change the 'actual' (utc) time you are really changing the time (making it earlier or later than what it was). Suddenly that record will be ordered differently compared to other records from other countries where the tz rules did not change.

Comment: @Eddy Time zone rules change for past time if someone applies a patch late. I'm not being flippant here, I've seen it happen.

Comment: @couling is correct. The question is should the past times (which were incorrectly updated) be retroactively "fixed" when in possession of the corrected ZIC data? The sort order would change. I'm not sure which behavior is better, but I'm leaning toward keeping the incorrect time. From a development POV it's usually better to be consistently wrong than to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about the offset, you should store the actual offset. Storing the timezone identifier is not that same thing as timezones can, and do, change over time. By storing the timezone offset, you can calculate the correct local time at the time of the event, rather than the local time based on the current offset. You may still want to store the timezone identifier, if it's important to know what actual timezone event was considered to have happened in.

Remember, time is a physical attribute, but a timezone is a political one.

Comment: You just gave the inverse of my argument that offset is not enough and you need the timezone identifier. The offset is not enough, see my explanation. But I'm not sure about your argument that the timezone identifier is not enough as well. Remember in my solution we store the localtime, and to quote Dan Grossman "September 1st, 1PM America/New_York" will never become 12PM or 2PM no matter what DST does. But what about the cached UTC timestamp used for comparisons, would the relative sort order of dates in the past change when the DST rules change?

Comment: They do change, see couling's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert to UTC you can order and compare the records 
If you add the name of the timezone it originated from you can represent it in it's original tz and be able to add/substract timeperiods like weeks, months etc (instead of elapsed time).

In your question you state that this is not enough because DST might be changed. DST makes calculating with dates (other than elapsed time) complicated and quite code intensive. Just like you need code to deal with leap years you need to take into account if for a given data / period you need to apply a DST correction or not. For some years the answer will be yes for others no. 
See [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANA_time_zone_database) for how complex those rules have become.

Storing the offset is basically storing the result of those calculations. That calculated offset is *only* valid for *that* given point in time and can't be applied *as is* to later or earlier points like you suggest in your question. You do the calculation on the UTC time and then convert the resulting time to the required timezone based on the rules that are active at that time in that timezone.

Note that there wasn't any DST before the first world war anywhere and date/time systems in databases handle those cases perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested in solutions for MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL and other DBMS that handle TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

Oracle converts with instant in time to UTC but keeps the time zone or UTC offset depending on what you pass. Oracle (correctly) makes a difference between the time zone and UTC offset and returns what you passed to you. This only costs two additional bytes.

Oracle does all calculations on `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in UTC. This is does not make a difference for adding months, but makes a difference for adding days as there is no daylight savings time. Note that the result of a calculation must always be a valid timestamp, e.g. adding one month to January 31st will throw an exception in Oracle as February 31st does not exist.